# Black box position exercise

Tags: html, css, position, box

I have this image and I need to reply it.
I already did most of the code, however I'm having some trouble doing the black box.
It needs to be:
 - on top of "redbox"
 - behind the "bluebox"
 - on top of "blueinbox"

[image]

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
.container {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.redbox {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    display: table;
    right: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.bluebox {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 60px 60px 0 0;
    display: table;
    right: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    border-left-style: dashed;
}
.blueinbox {
    background-color: #00aeef;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    float: right;
}
.ninja {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="redbox">
        </div>
        <div class="bluebox">
            <div class="blueinbox">
                <div class="ninja">
                    <p>NINJA!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
          
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Done.

```css
body {
 font: 500 16px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 2rem auto;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 background-color: #eee;
}

.box-red, .box-blue-light, .box-blue-dark, .box-black {
 position: absolute;
}

.box-red {
 top: 20px;
 right: 20px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.box-black {
 top: 40px;
 right: 40px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #000;
}

.box-blue-light {
 top: 80px;
 right: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #05adeb;
}
.box-blue-light::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: #000;
}
.box-blue-light h5 {
 margin-top: 2rem;
 font: 500 1rem 'Open Sans';
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 text-align: center;
}

.box-blue-dark {
 top: 60px;
 right: 60px;
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 border-left-style: dashed;
 background: #fff url("https://media1.giphy.com/media/fLg3MEWdgH5Ti/200.gif");
}
.box-blue-dark::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(170,50,90,.25)
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="box-red"></div>
  <div class="box-black"></div>
  <div class="box-blue-dark"></div>
  <div class="box-blue-light"><h5>NINJA!<h5></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahahah...
Loved that gif.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, my pleasure :)

Answer (score -1):

**Add z-index:1; to .bluebox.**

```css
body {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
}
.container {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.redbox {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    display: table;
    right: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
.bluebox {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 60px 60px 0 0;
    display: table;
    right: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    border-left-style: dashed;
}
.blueinbox {
    background-color: #00aeef;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    float: right;
}
.blackbox {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    float: right;
}
.ninja {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="redbox">
            <div class="blackbox"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bluebox">
            <div class="blueinbox">
                <div class="ninja">
                    <p>NINJA!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The "blackbox" is not of front of the "blueinbox"